# Cocoa suppress formatter errors with binding

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an NSTextField with a NumberFormatter. Without binding the value to anything, entering an invalid value and pressing tab/enter will just beep and retain focus in the field. This is great.

I need my controller to receive continuous updates of the value though, so I create a binding but suddenly find that the behaviour changes. Now with invalid input, a modal error will presented. I don't understand why it changes, but my question is: How can I get the original non-error-presenting behaviour while using bindings?

One thing I've tried is adding the following NSControlTextEditingDelegate functions to my controller:

```
    func control(_ control: NSControl, didFailToFormatString string: String, errorDescription error: String?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
        do {
            try self.commitEditingWithoutPresentingError()
            return true
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
```

But it hangs on `commitEditingWithoutPresentingError()`. (Not sure if this function is buggy, I've tried it elsewhere and it also hangs when there's invalid input, while `commitEditing()` works fine.)

In any case, I feel like there should be a relatively straight forward to achieve this, given that it's the default behaviour when bindings aren't in use, so is there is something simple I'm missing?

Comment: The binding displays the error. If you don't want the alert then don't use the binding.

Answer (score 0):

In retrospect, there was a fairly obvious solution I was missing. Assuming your bindings do not allow nil, you can just check control.objectValue for nil to see if the input is invalid:

```
    func control(_ control: NSControl, didFailToFormatString string: String, errorDescription error: String?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
        if control.objectValue == nil {
            NSSound.beep()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```